# number of cycles in arbitrary graph

Tags: graph-theory

Show that $G$ contains at least $\epsilon - v + \omega$ distinct cycles, where $\epsilon$ denotes the number of edges, $v$ denotes the number of vertices, and $\omega$ denotes the number of components in graph $G$

Comment: Hint. If you add an edge to a spanning tree you obtain a cycle. Adding distinct edges gives you distinct cycles.

Comment: @Jernej I would post this as an answer, there's not really anything more to the question than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. If you add an edge to a spanning tree you obtain a cycle. Adding distinct edges gives you distinct cycles